# Keeping track of book edits?

Tags: todonotes, trackchanges

I'm currently preparing a new edition of an old textbook: I need some way of keeping track of what I need to do, and what I have done.

Is there any software which plays nicely with LaTeX for this sort of thing?  I don't know if `todonotes` would be my best bet, or something else.

Comment: Yes, `todonotes` is good. It has a command \listoftodos that takes all the notes you've written and puts them in a list (along with the page where the note was written). It doesn't list what you've done though.

Comment: Any version control software can do this. `subversion` and `git` are both good and have solid support packages for cooperation with LaTeX (if that's a concern i.e. you can use version info in your document - if you don't care about that, any VCS you fancy will work fine). Note that the point of this is that the software keeps track so you don't have to. Fix mes and to dos and comments require you to keep track. But you are human and therefore (probably) useless at this. Your computer, on the other hand, is a computer and therefore excellent at this. Hence the idea of VCS.

Comment: `latexdiff` etc. is good for displaying changes if you go this way.

Comment: @cfr That question mostly focuses on multiple-authorship so not necessarily a duplicate. Because this needs also proper feature-tracking and todos.

Comment: A VCS is still an (if not *the*) answer. Assuming you're an academic, you can get a [free micro account](https://github.com/blog/1775) from Github, which includes [5 private repositories](https://github.com/pricing). Use their issue tracking to maintain your list of what needs to be done, and as you commit changes, you can automatically close the issues with changelog notes. Your institution may have internally hosted services comparable to Github as well.